# Verify Xcode Command Line Tools Install in Bash Script

Tags: xcode, macos, bash

I am creating a bash script to setup a development environment. As part of my script I need to install Xcode Command Line Tools and I don't want the script to continue execution until the installation has been completed.

When I run:

```
xcode-select --install
```

It prints that an install has been requested or that it has already been installed. I want to be able to wait until the message changes to already being installed.

The relevant part of my script is as follows:

```
check="$(xcode-\select --install)"
echo "$check"
str="xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools\n"
while [[ "$check" == "$str" ]];
do
    check="$(xcode-\select --install)"
    sleep 1
done
```

Unfortunately `$check` is always empty because `xcode-select --install` does not return anything and instead echoes the message to the terminal.

Comment: Is it outputting that message to standard error? Does `xcode-select --install 2>&1` help?

Comment: In the _"... relevant part of my script ..."_ you have `check="$(xcode-\select --install)"`, shouldn't that be `check="$(xcode-select --install)"`?  in other words, no _backslash_ between the `-` and `s` in `xcode-select`.

Comment: Without the slash I got errors in the rest of my script because `select` is a reserved word in bash

Comment: Interesting, I'm using OS X too and it does not throw an error for me without the _backslash_, in a script or from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I know you have probably already solved this issue, I had a crack at this problem today, and discovered that it prints to stderr and not stdout. This is the code I used to determine whether Xcode is installed or not:

```
check=$((xcode-\select --install) 2>&1)
echo $check
str="xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools"
while [[ "$check" == "$str" ]];
do
  osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "xcode command-line tools missing." buttons "OK" default button 1 with title "xcode command-line tools"'
  exit;  
done
```

Hope this helps someone in the future :)